# Custom Fonts with Cocosbuilder-HTML5

Tags: html, fonts, cocos2d-iphone, customization

I have a project where i'm using custom fonts (Century Gothic.ttf & Century Gothic Bold.ttf) and I can see it in my graphical interface but when i'm checking it with Safari or Chrome the fonts change and i don't know how fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: where did you put the font files in your project hierarchy?

Comment: Yes it's included at the hierarchy resources and when i'm publishing the project the ttf file isn't included so i can't see the user custom font.